# Parsing RSS2.0 feeds using Pull Parser on Android

Tags: android, exception, rss, xmlpullparser

I am trying to parse a RSS2.0 feed, obtained from a remote server, on my Android device using XML Pull Parser.

```
// get a parser instance and set input,encoding 
XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();  
parser.setInput(getInputStream(), null);
```

I am getting invalid token exceptions after a few items have been parsed:

> Error parsing document. (position:line
>   -1, column -1) caused by: org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException:
>   At line 158, column 25: not
>   well-formed (invalid token)

Strangely, when I download the feed XML on the device, bundle it inside the raw folder and then run the same code. Everything works fine.

What could be the problem here? How do I validate the XML before I parse it on device?

[EDIT: If this is set: `parser.setProperty(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_VALIDATION,true);` parsing fails immediately]
Thanks.

Comment: Is Pull the only parser you will consider using?

Comment: I am doing this on Mobile so I prefer not to use DOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted an answer to this in your other post: http://www.coderanch.com/t/495391/XML/Parsing-RSS-feeds-XML-Pull#2230731